# Calling each iteration with a nested loop (Javascript, node js, readlinesync)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to solve this problem but I do not know how to display each iteration (each of the twelve months) with console.log.

The problem is: Write a program that uses nested loops to collect data and 
calculate the average rainfall over a period of years. 
The program should first ask for the number of years. 
The outer loop will iterate once for each year. 
The inner loop will iterate twelve times, once for each month. 
Each iteration of the inner loop will ask the user for the inches of 
rainfall for that month. After all iterations, the program should 
display the number of months, the total inches of rainfall, and the 
average rainfall per month for the entire period.

This is what I have so far:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var years = readlineSync.questionInt('Enter the number of years: ');

for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
    var monthlyrainfall = readlineSync.questionInt('How many inches of rainfall was there this month? ');
  }
}
```

Comment: Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) -- [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22424760)

Answer (score 0):

The missing point was how to calculate a sum of values inside a loop. Take a look at this code, the vars `totalInchesOfRain` and `averageRainfallPerMonth` will calculate the values.

```
var readlineSync= require('readline-sync');

var years = readlineSync.questionInt('Enter the number of years: ');

var totalInchesOfRain = 0;
for (i=0; i < years ; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<11; j++){
        var monthlyRainFall = readlineSync.questionInt('How many inches of rainfall was there this month? ');

        totalInchesOfRain += monthlyRainFall;
    }
}

var averageRainfallPerMonth = totalInchesOfRain / (years * 12);
```